# what is the correct antlr comment lexer rule to exlude ampersand but only if it is at the end?

Tags: antlr

I need a lexer rule for a comment that does not include '&' at the end of a line.

'&' is a line continuation but is also a valid character in the middle of a comment.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar Test;

begin
    : line+
    ;

line
    : command? NEW_LINE    #CommandLine
    ;


command
    : PRINT STRINGLITERAL
    ;

STRINGLITERAL
    : '"' .*? '"'
    ;

PRINT : 'print';

NEW_LINE
    : ('\r'? '\n')
    | '\\'
    ;

LINE_CONTINUE
    : '&' [ \t]* NEW_LINE -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

COMMENT
    :  '!' ~[\r\n!&]* '!'? -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

WS
    : [ \T]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

The above works until I have a comment like:

```
! rock & roll
```

Here is some valid text that I need to parse:

```
print "hello world" ! rock & roll
print ! comment here &
    "hello world"
```

Here is the output:

```
line 1:30 token recognition error at: '& r'
line 1:33 token recognition error at: 'o'
line 1:34 token recognition error at: 'l'
line 1:35 token recognition error at: 'l'
[@0,3:7='print',<2>,1:3]
[@1,8:8=' ',<6>,channel=1,1:8]
[@2,9:21='"hello world"',<1>,1:9]
[@3,22:22=' ',<6>,channel=1,1:22]
[@4,23:29='! rock ',<5>,channel=1,1:23]
[@5,36:37='\r\n',<3>,1:36]
[@6,38:42='print',<2>,2:0]
[@7,43:43=' ',<6>,channel=1,2:5]
[@8,44:58='! comment here ',<5>,channel=1,2:6]
[@9,59:61='&\r\n',<4>,channel=1,2:21]
[@10,62:65='    ',<6>,channel=1,3:0]
[@11,66:78='"hello world"',<1>,3:4]
[@12,79:80='\r\n',<3>,3:17]
[@13,81:80='<EOF>',<-1>,4:19]
(begin (line (command print "hello world") \r\n) (line (command print "hello world") \r\n))
```

note that @roll is not recognized

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the solution to this is to change the COMMENT rule to:

```
COMMENT
    :  '!' ~[\r\n]* ('!'|LINE_CONTINUE)? -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

the new output is then:

```
[@0,3:7='print',<2>,1:3]
[@1,8:8=' ',<6>,channel=1,1:8]
[@2,9:21='"hello world"',<1>,1:9]
[@3,22:22=' ',<6>,channel=1,1:22]
[@4,23:35='! rock & roll',<5>,channel=1,1:23]
[@5,36:37='\r\n',<3>,1:36]
[@6,38:42='print',<2>,2:0]
[@7,43:43=' ',<6>,channel=1,2:5]
[@8,44:61='! comment here &\r\n',<5>,channel=1,2:6]
[@9,62:65='    ',<6>,channel=1,3:0]
[@10,66:78='"hello world"',<1>,3:4]
[@11,79:80='\r\n',<3>,3:17]
[@12,81:80='<EOF>',<-1>,4:19]
(begin (line (command print "hello world") \r\n) (line (command print "hello world") \r\n))
```

Note:

```
[@8,44:61='! comment here &\r\n',<5>,channel=1,2:6]
```

the above comment now has &\r\n on the end but that is ok.